# How to perform assertion using phpunit for the if statement

Tags: php, phpunit

How could I write the PHPunit testing for the below code?

```
 public function addOptions()
    {
        $data['option1'] = [a, b, c];
        $data['option2'] = [ab,bc,de];
        $data['option3'] = [c, d, e];
        $data['option4'] = [dd, ef, fh];
        if ((! in_array($data['option1'], $data['option2'] )) || (! in_array($data['option3'], $data['option4']))) {
            trigger_error('Value not found in option array!'); // I could see in the coverage that this line is not executed.
        }
    }
```

Could someone help to solve this issue?
Thanks

Comment: in_array expects the first parameter to be the value you search for, the second is the array. You only passed one argument to in_array($data['option1']).

Comment: @demianh, I didn't get you, I passed 2 arguments to in_array()

Comment: not sure what you want to test exactly, but the in_array() function expects two parameters like this: in_array('a', $data['option1'])

Comment: I want to test the If statement using Phpunit .

Comment: The if statement is still not working as you expect. See the description of in_array: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.in-array.php i suspect it does something different than you expect.

Comment: Also, with PHPUnit you can use $this->assertTrue(false) instead of trigger_error to fail a test, maybe that helps.